# Estimating the posterior predictive distribution post regression adjustment when doing Approximate Bayesian Computation

Tags: regression, bayesian, posterior, adjustment, approximate-bayesian-computation

I'm currently correcting the parameter values of the posterior distribution estimated with Approximate Bayesian Computation. The correction is obtained using a multiple weighted linear regression model to get closer to the real posterior as proposed by Beaumont et al 2002. From that corrected posterior, I want to estimate the posterior predictive distribution, but I'm worried about how to draw the parameter values from the corrected posterior?

Comment: Could you give more details on what you mean by regression adjustment? Is it in the spirit of Beaumont et al. (2002)? I do not think there is any connection with posterior predictive checks, except for the approximation impact of ABC.

Comment: For the moment I have been using the ABC (Csillery et al 2015) package from R Cran and I'm using the local linear regression adjustment for the correction between S(obs-data) and S(pseudo-data).

Comment: Thank you Xi'an.  Am I better to use the non-parametric form of regression adjustment proposed by Beaumont et al (2002)?

Comment: I did not check but was under the impression these adjustments were the same.